# Why the function is invoked for every input in React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I try to learn react component rendering but the problem is that I have a login page with 2 input field and 1 button as:

```
function LoginPage() {

    const [username, changeUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, changePassword] = useState('');

    const loginRequest = async (username, password) => {
        let response = await service.loginRequest(username, password);
        console.log(response);
    }

    return (
        <Card hoverable className='transaction-button-card'>
            <h1>Enter username and password</h1>
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Username"
                   onChange={e => changeUsername(e.target.value)}
                   value={username}></input>
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Password"
                   onChange={e => changePassword(e.target.value)}
                   value={password}></input>
            <Button onClick={loginRequest(username, password)}
                    className='withdraw-deposit-button'>Login/Deposit</Button>
        </Card>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

When the page is rendered the function **loginRequest(username, password)** automatically triggered once and *for every input characters* to input fields are also triggering the same function and sending request for each input char. How can I solve this problem? (I don't want to send request automatically when the page is opened and send request with only with button). I would appreciate if you define the problem.

Comment: `onClick={loginRequest(username, password)}` needs to be `onClick={() => loginRequest(username, password)}`. Right now you're calling the function immediately, during rendering

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks mate. If you give it as an answer, I would like to mark it as correct solution. And thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`
function LoginPage() {

```
const [username, changeUsername] = useState('');
const [password, changePassword] = useState('');

const loginRequest = async (username, password) => {
    let response = await service.loginRequest(username, password);
    console.log(response);
}

return (
    <Card hoverable className='transaction-button-card'>
        <h1>Enter username and password</h1>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Username"
               onChange={e => changeUsername(e.target.value)}
               value={username}></input>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Password"
               onChange={e => changePassword(e.target.value)}
               value={password}></input>
        <Button onClick={() => loginRequest(username, password)}
                className='withdraw-deposit-button'>Login/Deposit</Button>
    </Card>
);
```

}

export default LoginPage;
`